Passing images loaded from dynamically-built `require` URLs through props in React components
So I'm building out a simple restaurant app in React and have a series of .jpg images. In my Specials.jsx component, I've built an array of objects whose properties include image. I then map over this array to render <Special /> (not Specials) elements for each object. I first tried to require a dynamic image pathway so I wouldn't have to import all the files manually, but this didn't work. I console.logged the pathways to make sure that were being built as intended and matched the image locations (they were and they did). But the images weren't being loaded, so I imported the first image to test it out, and placed it's alias in the image property of my array. This still didn't load the images. I then imported the image directly into the Special.jsx module and it worked fine, but because of the way I'm rendering it, resulted in the image taking up every spot in the rendered array. I'm just not sure what's going on and if there's is some problem with handling images in this way. For context, I've bootstrapped my app with create-react-app (I can't change that because this is an assignment that requires a specific dev process).
This is my Specials.jsx module:
const Specials = () => {
    return (
        <main className={styles.layout}>
            {specials.map(special => {
                return <Special key={special.title} data={special} />
            })}
        </main>
    );
};

export default Specials;

This is my Special.jsx module:
const Special = ({ data }) => {
    return (
        <article className={styles.article}>
            <img src={data.img} alt={data.title} />
            <h2>{data.title}</h2>
            <p>{data.desc}</p>
            <p>{data.price}</p>
        </article>
    );
};

export default Special;

Let's say my array is this:
const specials = [
    {
        title: 'Campanelle',
        desc: 'Fresh campanelle pasta tossed in pesto alla genovese and topped with roasted pine nuts and fried kale.',
        price: '$31',
        image: // Depends on how I load them
    }
};

I first loaded in an image called Campanelle-min.jpg like this (didn't work):
// Specials.jsx
const getImagePath = (imageName) => {
    return require(`../../assets/images/postcompress/${imageName}-min.jpg`);
};
const specials = [
    {
        title: 'Campanelle',
        desc: 'Fresh campanelle pasta tossed in pesto alla genovese and topped with roasted pine nuts and fried kale.',
        price: '$31',
        image: getImagePath('Campanelle')
    }
};

Then like this (still didn't work):
// Specials.jsx
import Campanelle from '../../assets/images/postcompress/Campanelle-min.jpg';

const specials = [
    {
        title: 'Campanelle',
        desc: 'Fresh campanelle pasta tossed in pesto alla genovese and topped with roasted pine nuts and fried kale.',
        price: '$31',
        image: Campanelle
    }
};

Then I loaded it the same way into Special.jsx (now it works, but doesn't let me import all of the images into each different rendered <Special />):
import Campanelle from '../../assets/images/postcompress/Campanelle-min.jpg';

const Special = ({ data }) => {
    return (
        <article className={styles.article}>
            <img src={Campanelle} alt={data.title} />
            <h2>{data.title}</h2>
            <p>{data.desc}</p>
            <p>{data.price}</p>
        </article>
    );
};

export default Special;


what was the error when you have tried this example: import Campanelle from '.../Campanelle-min.jpg'; const specials = [     {         title: 'Campanelle',         desc: 'Fresh campanelle pasta tossed in pesto alla genovese and topped with roasted pine nuts and fried kale.',         price: '$31',         image: Campanelle     } }; (second to last?)

It didn't give me an error per se, it was more just a bug. The images simply never loaded.

I ended up finding a workaround by importing everything into my subcomponent directly and building a switch statement that changed the <img> elements' src attribute based on the title of the special dish, but this isn't very maintable in the long run and required much more code than I'd assume would be necessary.

You can try putting images in public folder if you want to map images.
then you can put in src of img tag as:
 src={`folder_in_public_folder_with_images/${imagepath_or_name}.extension`} 

imagepath or name will be variable mapped using either an array with names defined or as you feel good.
